# How to transform a gameObject to a transform variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, positioning, gameobject

I want to make a script to put a gameObject to the start position it had when it entered the scene  when I click a button in unity

Comment: So what are you having trouble with? Save the initial transform of your object at the initialization of your behavior, and restore it when you need to?

Comment: exactly, I want to store the start Position and then when I want I wil just press the menu button and the gameObject will "go" to the startPosition

Comment: Please make an honest effort to code this yourself and provide us code where you get stuck. StackOverflow is meant for debugging and helping you when you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Save the initial position and call the return code to the first location via the following steps:

```cs
public Vector3 basePosition; // save the initial position

private void Start() => basePosition = transform.position;

public void ReturnBack() => transform.position = basePosition;
```

---

[image]
[image]

Comment: I need to get player's transform because with only this line of code nothing really happens

Comment: @GameDevUnity You can save rotation and scale in other variables as above, what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. A **GameObject** cannot be transformed into a **Transform**. However, each **GameObject** has access to its own **Transform**: `gameObject.transform`

Answer (score 0):

Just declare a "Vector3" variable and then you use the "gameObject.transform.position =" and then the name of the variable you've created.

```
var new_position = Vector3(0, 0, 0);
gameObject.transform.position = new_position;
```

Comment: In which function should I add this lines of code?